# Issue when building UWP app with Qt UWP x32/x64 Kits

Tags: c++, qt, uwp

I have downloaded from [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt) directory `cppwinrt` it contains the header files to use `UWP API` with `Qt`. The `Qt` version is `5.9.3`.

I have included it in `.pro` file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Users/cobra/Downloads/Downloads Data/cppwinrt/10.0.16299.0"
```

**.h file:**

```
#include <winrt/windows.devices.enumeration.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "windowsapp")
using namespace winrt;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Devices::Enumeration;
```

**.cpp file:**

```
 init_apartment(); //this initializes com
 DeviceInformationCollection infos = DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync().get();

 for (const auto &info : infos) {
      qDebug() << QString::fromWCharArray(info.Name().c_str());
 }
```

I want to get some device information. The problem is, it compiles only for `ARMV7` kit. On `x32/x64` kits it displays a lot of errors:

[image]
[image]

I have checked it and all errors are from `cppwinrt` directory where the header files located. How to fix it to build for `x32/x64` kits?

**Update:** 
Without `UWP API` includes, the application compiles and runs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by installing `Qt` extension to `Visual Studio`and selecting `Win SDK` to `10.0.16299.0`, now it compiles for all architectures.